# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, fastapi

I am returning my input data from neo4j using fastapi. But i am getting this error

```py
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/workspace/graph-app/main.py", line 67, in createusernode
    return {data}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I was unable to return the data using the cypher can some one point out the changes i need to make to the code to return the data

```py
class usermodel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    weight: int
    nativety: str
    brith_type: str

@app.post('/createuser')
async def createusernode(node:usermodel):
    driver_neo4j = connection()
    session = driver_neo4j.session()
    q1 = """
    create(n:user{name:$name, age:$age, weight: $weight, nativety: $nativety, birth_type: $birth_type}) return n.name as name
    """
    x = {"name": node.name, "age":node.age, "weight":node.weight, "nativety":node.nativety, "birth_type":node.brith_type}
    results = session.run(q1,x)
    # data=[{"Name":row["name"]}for row in results][0]["Name"]
    data = [{"Data": row["name"]} for row in results]
    return {data}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a `set` of your data? What if you tried `return set(data)`? Right now you're trying to use a list as an element in a `set` (rather than each item in a list), and lists aren't hashable since they're mutable.

Comment: @wkl then i am getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` error

Comment: Exactly what is your goal? It seems just `return data` would be good enough if you only want to return the names (not sure why they need to be in a dictionary with `"name"` as the key)?